# Deploying dockerize Fast api to google cloud engine

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, fastapi, gcloud, large-language-model

Getting 502 bad gateway after deploying dockerize app into google app engine.
Hi, i am trying to deploy docker based API into google app engine. Please find below code for your reference.
Initialfile.py is main file and remaining docker-compose.yaml, app.yaml  etc

```
#docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    # command: sh -c "uvicorn initialfile:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=7005 --reload"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

```
#docker-compose-depoy.yml
version: '3.9'

services:
  gcloud:
    image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
    volumes:
      - gcp-creds:/creds
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      - CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/creds

volumes:
  gcp-creds:
```

```
#app.yaml

runtime: python39
instance_class: F4_1G
```

```
#dockerfile

FROM python:3.11.5-bookworm

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn","initialfile:app","--host","0.0.0.0","--port","8000"]
```

Answer (score 1):

502 error indicate that possibly the server is not started listening yet.

You are trying to listen on port 8000 try it on 8080 as per GAE documentation -
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listening_to_port_8080

> **Listening to port 8080** 
> The App Engine front end will route incoming requests to the appropriate module on port 8080. You must be sure that your application code is listening on 8080.

```
#docker-compose.yaml
...

services:
  ...
    ...
    ...
    ports:
      - 8080:8000
    ...
```